# Delete last N entries from the database by X field using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-trigger

I have a table in SQL Server which keeps password histories of users to prevent a user from re-using a previously used password.

```
CREATE TABLE user_password_histories 
(
    id BIGINT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT user_password_histories_pk PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
    ,password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
    ,user_id BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,created_at DATETIME DEFAULT GETUTCDATE() NOT NULL
    ,updated_at DATETIME
)
```

However, I only want to maintain only a list of 10 password histories for the user. So, I am thinking to use a trigger to only keep 10 histories for per user during insertion.

The partial solution that I came up with is this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_user_password_histories  
ON user_password_histories
AFTER INSERT
AS
    DELETE FROM user_password_histories
    WHERE user_password_histories.user_id = Inserted.user_id // This will not work
      AND user_password_histories.id NOT IN (SELECT t2.id
                                             FROM user_password_histories t2
                                             WHERE t2.id = user_password_histories.id
                                             ORDER BY t2.created_at DESC 
                                                 OFFSET 10 ROWS)
GO
```

But the problem here is that `Inserted` can have multiple entries. So, I am not sure how to solve this issue or the best way to resolve this issue.

Comment: I honestly smell a bigger problem; that looks like you're storing plain text passwords in your databases, not hashes and salts. I could be wrong, as you may well be reusing the salt from the `[User]` table and `password` is salted; but if it were hashed I could expect the column to be an `nvarchar` not a `varchar`. That is a much bigger problem you should be looking to solve first, in my opinion.

Comment: Just wondering what makes you think that I am using plain password here just by looking at the database schema? I am not storing plain password..they are all encrypted.

Comment: I'd just finished adding my reasoning to my original comment, as you posted that comment. But, like I said, it was more of a "smell"; i might be wrong, but the DDL of the table makes it look like it does have that flaw.

Comment: Triggers should never be a first resort; `INSERT` triggers that `DELETE` seem especially evil. Unless you really have a need to somehow mass-import passwords for multiple users (?) it's much more maintainable to set up a stored procedure for this logic instead.

Comment: Also recommended, if allowable at your company, is to use current NIST guidance on passwords. Scroll down to section 5.1.1.1 here: https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html

Comment: As much as I totally agree that this looks like plain text passwords and that a trigger is the wrong job for this the reason this fails is because in your delete statement you don't have the inserted table in the query. You would need to change the where clause to a join so that the inserted table is part of the query. I would make this delete logic very different if it were me. It would be part of my insert stored procedure.

Comment: I think you are right stored proc may be the right way to solve this issue. As for password like I said it is encrypted and using LibSodium which does not require you to store salt explicitly. @HardCode I looked at the documentation but section 5.1.1.1 does not mention anything about password reqs title says `5.1.1.1 Memorized Secret Authenticators`. But it looks like good article to read thank you.

Comment: @nicholasnet they use "memorized secret" as a synonym for password. You'll want to read through all the sections about memorized secrets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally I think I found a solution for this. I tested this with batch insert and single insert and it works !!! I had to use `cursor` to solve this. I am posting my solution here so that others might benefit from it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_user_password_histories_insert ON user_password_histories
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    DELETE uph FROM user_password_histories uph
    WHERE uph.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM Inserted)
    AND uph.id NOT IN (
        SELECT id FROM (
            SELECT user_password_histories.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_password_histories.user_id ORDER BY user_password_histories.created_at DESC) AS rn
            FROM user_password_histories
            WHERE user_password_histories.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM Inserted)
        ) t
        WHERE t.rn <= 10
    )
go
```

This solution may not be a good one to use in all scenarios but it works perfectly in this case.

Comment: Only a hint: Create a subquery which selects the last 10 passwords for each user. Then make an outer join with the main table, and delete all records which are NOT in the subquery.

Comment: and just BTW: I doubt that keeping the passwords is a "mass of data", so I would just keep them.

Comment: @SQLPolice that was good suggestion I did not think about that thank you. I made the edits.